# Use Apache's Name Based Virtual Host to Redirect to Internal IP

Tags: apache-httpd, apache-virtualhost

I'm toying with a new setup at home, and not sure if what I'm trying to do is possible or not.

I've got my domain's DNS pointed to my WAN IP and being answered by Apache on an Ubuntu 14.04 server on port 80 and everything there works fine.  However, I want to mix it up a little bit and here's what I would want to accomplish.

Virtual hosts running on the apache server listening on name-based routing.  Something like:

```
wp.me.com -> forwarded to my Ubuntu server and fed Wordpress from Apache
fw.me.com -> forwarded to server and redirected to 192.168.1.1:8443 to access my firewall
wifi.me.com -> forwarded to server and redirected to 192.168.1.3:8080 to access WiFi
dev.me.com -> forwarded to server and fed from a separate directory in Apache
```

Is this something I can accomplish with VirtualHosts?

Answer (score 7):

Yes you can,

The first VirtualHost will point to your Wordpress site, the other VirtualHosts will be setup as Reverse Proxy to your other internal devices.

Example:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    Servername fw.me.com
    ProxyPass / https://192.168.1.1:8443/
    ProxyPassReverse / https://192.168.1.1:8443/
</VirtualHost>
```

See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html

And if you are exposing your internal stuff to the outside world, make sure you properly secured your Apache (ie. username/password protection, IP level access etc.)

Comment: I would assume the user has a sub domain `fw` to work this out ? and instead of sub domain can it be different `URL` example: `http://me.com/fw`

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done with apache rewrite rules for cases when you are not forwarding tomcat as described by Lambert.

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^wp.me.com$

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://your.apache.wordpress.com/$1 [R=301,L]