# Apache redirect certain url or subdomain to internal ip

Tags: apache-httpd, apache-virtualhost, reverse-proxy

I have a gitlab server next to my web server running on my home network. On my web server I run Apache2 with some domains. One of them is example.com. Now my aim is that the user receives the gitlab login page when visiting something like example.com/gitlab or gitlab.example.com. Actually I do not care whether the redirection happens from a certain url or a subdomain. I've already tried quite much but nothing of this worked for me (probably I did it wrong all times).

I also read some related forum posts like

- [Use apache virtual host to redirect a subdomain to internal ip preserving passed port](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/349218/use-apache-virtual-host-to-redirect-a-subdomain-to-internal-ip-preserving-passed)
- [Use Apache's Name Based Virtual Host to Redirect to Internal IP](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209300/use-apaches-name-based-virtual-host-to-redirect-to-internal-ip)
- https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/apache-redirect-to-internal-server-919321/
- ...

But I didn't get anything up and running.

My *default.conf* is configured that it always redirects Port 80 to Port 443 (HTTPS).

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com

    Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com/
    [...]
</VirtualHost>
```

So here is my *example.com.conf* before:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example.com

    SSLEngine on

    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>
    <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>

    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

First I tried to redirect **from a certain url**. I added:

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPass /gitlab http://192.168.0.115:80/
ProxyPassReverse /gitlab http://192.168.0.115:80/
```

This does not work completly but if I enter the url, I get *"404 The requested URL /users/sign_in was not found on this server"*. '/users/sign_in' is the path of the login page of my gitlab so server, so at least something seems to work.
Strange to me is that it works if I redirect the root directory to my internal IP:

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPass / http://192.168.0.113:80/
ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.0.113:80/
```

This works but now I can't access my actual website anymore.

Then I tried redirection **from a subdomain**. I added:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName gitlab.example.com

    ProxyPass / http://192.168.0.113/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.0.113/
</VirtualHost>
```

But I receive *"The website is unreachable"*. I don't even get the subdomain running.

Comment: <Location /gitlab>
      ProxyRequests Off
      ProxyPass / http://192.168.0.113:80/
      ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.0.113:80/
    </Location>
?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I had to change it to <Location /gitlab> ProxyPass http://192.168.0.113/ ProxyPassReverse http://192.168.0.113/ </Location> because ProxyRequests is not allowed in Location and ProxyPass shall not specify any path within Location. Unfortunatly I get again the error "404 The requested URL /users/sign_in was not found on this server". If I change the Location to root (like this <Location />) then it works again. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Might have to use mod_rewrite to strip the /gitlab bit out.  Something like:

```
rewriteBase "/gitlab"
rewriteRule "^gitlab/(.*)" "http:/192.168.0.113/$1" [P]
```

See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/proxy.html